# Javascript insert element below the current row in fluid grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bACZd/

I am building a simple grid layout with plain JS. The grid consists of 16 "tiles" now, but will grow later. The website is designed responsive, so the grid adjusts from 8x1 to 2x8 fluidly, see attached images.
Now what I want to do is show an additional container, if one of the tiles is clicked.
This container is 100% wide, so it should obviously appear below the current row in the grid. I could solve this with a massive, nested switch-case, hard coding all the ranges for the tile positions. But I think there must be a way to solve this.

[image: Example grid]

As you can see in the image, the grid is resized with breakpoints.  I want to insert my gallery container right after the last element in a row.
[image]

In the script, I use a switch case for the number of columns available. But I don't get further from here.

```
// ...
switch (columns_currently_shown) {
    case 1:
        place_after_number = current_element;
        break;
    case 2:
        // ???
        break;
    case 3:
        // ???
        break;
    case 4:
        // ???
        break;
    }
  var place_after_this = document.getElementById("tile" + place_after_number);
  insertAfter(place_after_this, gallery_element_to_insert);
}
```

And please do not advise me to use jQuery. I know that it would make many things simpler, or that I could just use libraries. But I try to learn JS and want to do it this way :)

**Edit: --bump-- it would be helpful if someone would actually read more than the word "grid" in this post.**